# How to get the count of Value repetition under array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array which have some repetition count. I want to get the count of that repetition.
My array is like this:

```
var array = [
    { asset: "A", sector: "Hospital" },
    { asset: "B", sector: "Hardware" },
    { asset: "C", sector: "Networking" },
    { asset: "D", sector: "Networking" },
    { asset: "E", sector: "Food" },
    { asset: "F", sector: "Hospital" },
    { asset: "G", sector: "Hardware" },
    { asset: "H", sector: "Industrial" },
    { asset: "I", sector: "Transport" },
    { asset: "J", sector: "Hardware" },
    { asset: "K", sector: "Networking" },
    { asset: "L", sector: "Transport" }
]
```

Now I want the Repetition count something like this also in sorted order like this:

```
final_array = [
    { sector: 'Hardware', count: 3 },
    { sector: 'Networking', count: 3 },
    { sector: 'Hospital', count: 2 },
    { sector: 'Transport', count: 2 },
    { sector: 'Food', count: 1 },
    { sector: 'Industrial', count: 1 }
]
```

I don't get the clue from  where  can do this. I got many link but they solve the repetition under array not on Array of objects.

I use the one approach but that not solve my issue

```
var finalD = [];
c.forEach(x => {
    if (isSectorExists(x.sector, finalD) == true) {
        //Here I don't know how I will increase the counter.
    } else {
        finalD.push({ sector: x.sector, count: 1 });
    }
});

var isSectorExists = (sector, arr) => {
    return arr.some(function(el) {
        return el.sector === sector;
    });
};
```

I know that my approach was very long. Is someone have the best and easy approach for doing this kind of task. Any Help is really Appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Questions that ask for refinements to code that is already working are better suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an object `counts` with sector name as keys and an object that stores counts as values, iterate through your array and update those counts, and then finally get the values of that `counts` object.

```js
var array = [
      { asset: "A", sector: "Hospital" },
      { asset: "B", sector: "Hardware" },
      { asset: "C", sector: "Networking" },
      { asset: "D", sector: "Networking" },
      { asset: "E", sector: "Food" },
      { asset: "F", sector: "Hospital" },
      { asset: "G", sector: "Hardware" },
      { asset: "H", sector: "Industrial" },
      { asset: "I", sector: "Transport" },
      { asset: "J", sector: "Hardware" },
      { asset: "K", sector: "Networking" },
      { asset: "L", sector: "Transport" }
];
            
            
var counts = array.reduce((m, c) => {
    if (c.sector in m) m[c.sector].count += 1;
    else m[c.sector] = { sector: c.sector, count: 1};
    return m;
}, {});

let finalArray = Object.values(counts).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

console.log(finalArray);
```

This will get the counts in linear time (as opposed to calling `isSectorExists` for every element which would make it *O(n^2)*.

Comment: Thanks for provide the precious and shortest way to solve the issue. Really Appreciate for your help